# WC Lightbox, Zoom and Slider not loading

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have run the following code within my `functions.php`, however Lightbox, Zoom and the Slider ALL do not work. The CSS seems to load for the Swipe, however no javascript files are being loaded.

I have no errors, so what could be the issue? Is it involving the function code itself?

Running latest WooCommerce (v3.6.3) and latest Wordpress (v5.2)

```
function fd_theme_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => 100,
        'width'       => 400,
        'flex-height' => true,
        'flex-width'  => true,
        'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'fd_theme_support', 10 );
```

I am also using Bootstrap 4 as the framework for my website...could that be interrupting the function's processes at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone else may run into a similar issue, the problem I was having was that I hadn't added the `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` code into my `footer.php` file.

If it is not added, anything that you intent to load via the footer will not work! Took me a few weeks to figure out that one line of code was breaking my workflow...